# Firebase authentication issues, Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am having some issues with Firebase auth. I'm building an app using using Kotlin but keep retrieving the error **'W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.'**

I had this working previously, when I had set up the application using activities. I've now moved towards MVP architecture, but this seems to have broken my firebase authentication. I have also ensured that Email/Password sign in method has been enabled in the Firebase console.

If anyone could please take a look and hopefully you can see where I am going wrong. Many thanks.

SignInView

```
package org.wit.hikingtrails.views.signIn

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import org.wit.hikingtrails.databinding.ActivitySignInBinding
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import org.wit.hikingtrails.activities.SignUpActivity
import org.wit.hikingtrails.views.hikeList.HikeListView
import org.wit.hikingtrails.views.signUp.SignUpView

class SignInView : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var presenter: SignInPresenter
    private lateinit var binding: ActivitySignInBinding
    private lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        presenter = SignInPresenter( this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivitySignInBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)


        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        binding.textView.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, SignUpView::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        binding.button.setOnClickListener {
            val email = binding.emailEt.text.toString()
            val pass = binding.passET.text.toString()
            if (email.isNotEmpty() && pass.isNotEmpty()) {
                presenter.doLogin(email, pass)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Empty Fields Are not Allowed !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        if(firebaseAuth.currentUser != null){
            val intent = Intent(this, HikeListView::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

SignInPresenter:

```
package org.wit.hikingtrails.views.signIn

import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
import android.content.Intent
import android.util.Log
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import org.wit.hikingtrails.views.hikeList.HikeListView
import timber.log.Timber
import timber.log.Timber.i

class SignInPresenter (val view: SignInView)  {
    private lateinit var loginIntentLauncher : ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>

    init{
        registerLoginCallback()
    }
    var auth: FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()


    fun doLogin(email: String, pass: String) {
//        view.showProgress()
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).addOnCompleteListener(view) { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                val launcherIntent = Intent(view, HikeListView::class.java)
                loginIntentLauncher.launch(launcherIntent)
            } else {
                i("Login failed:")
//                val launcherIntent = Intent(view, HikeListView::class.java)
//                loginIntentLauncher.launch(launcherIntent)
            }
//            view.hideProgress()
        }
    }

    private fun registerLoginCallback(){
        loginIntentLauncher =
            view.registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult())
            {  }
    }

}
```

Comment: "W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null" is not an error, but a warning. That message has also been asked quite a few times before, so I recommend checking out: https://www.google.com/search?q=W%2FSystem%3A+Ignoring+header+X-Firebase-Locale+because+its+value+was+null

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that was having the same issue: The issue was with my API key. In kotlin, to debug, I used Timber.i( "signInWithCredential:failure ${task.exception?.message}") within the else statement of doLogin() in the presenter

Comment: Use code blocks for describe your code